# What does "unit" mean in "storage unit"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

What does *unit* mean in *storage unit*? From OALD I looked up, is it:

> 1. a single thing, person or group that is complete by itself but can also form part of something larger 
>      or 2. a single flat/apartment or house in a building or group of buildings containing a number of them (although this describes apartments, I figured it could relate?)

Or does it mean something else that's not covered here?

Comment: Is it possible for us to see the context in which you encountered this term **unit of storage**.

Comment: @Animadversor I actually came across the term through a forum discussion, a rather unpleasant topic of discussion I suppose about suicide, and someone suggested something about using rent-out storage units as a substitute for a garage if the need of garage is unavailable for suicide.

Comment: Too Localised. In general, a *storage unit* can be any size/any purpose, but I'm guessing OP is thinking of [storage of house contents, etc.](http://www.bigyellow.co.uk/) So really, in that context, *unit = **space, section, area*** (to put things in).

Comment: I think you have pretty well figured it out by extrapolating from the OALD definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, meaning 5 in OALD is what is intended: "a piece of furniture, especially a cupboard, that fits with and matches others of the same type".

See https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unit for a list of 10 meanings. They are all extrapolatable from the basic meaning of unit, an individual part of a greater whole/range/set of similar things.

Comment: so this sense applies not only to furnitures it could apply to rooms as well? because the storage unit I meant is the ones you rent out like a garage kind of. Also, I don't quite get some of the examples they gave with the definition, such as *floor/wall units, bedroom/kitchen units*, I could probably understand the use of kitchen unit, maybe the cupboards or something? but floor/wall units, bedroom units?

Comment: By the way, in English we consider **furniture** to be a non-count noun, so instead of *furnitures*, *furniture* would be better.

Comment: A wall unit is a piece of furniture. If you put the phrase "wall unit" into images.google.com, you will see some pictures of wall units. Ornaments, books and other things can be put on wall units. I personally have never said "floor unit, bedroom unit, kitchen unit", but these refer to shelves/cabinets and things like that. I have never referred to a room as a unit. An apartment (flat) could be called a unit in certain circumstances.